# Access elements inside reactjs structure

Tags: reactjs

How could I access the elements inside the children in this structure?

```
class MyDictionary extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var _this = this;
    var children = this.props.results.map((result, index) =>
      React.createElement(
        "div",
        { className: "col-sm-12" },
        React.createElement(SomeOtherClass, {
          key: result.id,
          name: result.name,
          index: result.index,
          activity: _this.props.index + 1, // using _this
          images: _this.props.image_labels // using _this
        })
      )
    );
    return React.createElement("div", null, children);
  }
}
return MyDictionary;
console.log(MyDictionary.children.image_labels);
```

When I try `console.log(MyDictionary.children.image_labels);` I get nothing back... I've tried multiple ways of doing this but no luck. Any suggestions/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  If you're trying to read information from a a child in a parent component, you'll need to pass in a callback function to the child to do it.

Comment: Further to @aelfric5578's point - the way you're trying to retrieve information goes against the actual lifecycle of the component - MyDictionary is a class, it hasn't been mounted and thus doesn't have any children/the render() method hasn't run yet. I would advise reading some more on the component lifecycle and parent/child relationships in React.